# MouseScroll event does not trigger when TextBox is scrollable

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, mousewheel

I found that when I attach a `MouseWheel` event to my `UserControl` or a `TextBox`, it does not trigger if the `TextBox` is scrollable. It will scroll the textbox and not trigger MouseWheel, can I make it such that it runs MouseWheel and then after doing something `e.Cancel` it so that the `TextBox` does not scroll?

### UPDATE: With Video & Code

**Video**

http://screenr.com/ZGF

**Code**

http://www.mediafire.com/?x3o09dz6dr5zoym

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox.MouseWheel += (s, e) =>
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Debug.WriteLine(rand.NextDouble());
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce this problem. Please post some example code showing this behavior

Comment: @Meleak, I've made a video + a simple project reproducing the problem, see update

Comment: Code link no longer valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean that the MouseWheel event on the *UserControl* won't trigger.  That's normal, the TextBox is happy to accept the message when it is multiline.  The reason that the MouseWheel event is not visible in the designer.  The parent window will only see the message when the control with the focus won't process it.

Not sure if you should fix this, the user would really expect the text box to scroll.  But you can by intercepting the message so the text box can't see it and passing the message to the parent.  Add a new class to your project, paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x20a && this.Parent != null) {
            PostMessage(this.Parent.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        }
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
}
```