# How can I make a TextBox scroll when the mouse wheel is turned in another control?

Tags: c#

I'm making an IRC client where the chat is displayed in a multi-line TextBox control named chatBox. Below the chat there is a single-line textBox named editBox where the user enters messages. I want the user to be able to scroll in the chatBox even while the editBox has the focus. Is there any way I can do that?

I've looked at the events for textBox and I can't find anything resembling a scroll event, and I've searched Google for an answer with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scroll directly, but you can move the cursor. You can move the cursor to the end of a text box, for example, with `textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length`.

By manipulating the selection you can emulate scrolling by using `textBox.ScrollToCaret()`.

Comment: The biggest problem is that I can't even find a way to detect when the mouse wheel is scrolled in the editBox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286173/mousescroll-event-does-not-trigger-when-textbox-is-scrollable (Includes a workaround for detecting MouseWheel events).

Comment: Wow, I'd already read that but I couldn't find a MouseWheel event. For some reason it's not in the properties box, I had to add the event handler in the code when the form loads. Thanks!